# How to Join Specific Max Row in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana

Hello I am performing a query in SAP HANA and trying to only take a unique record with the most recent item (in this case it is a contract start date):

The query I am running is this:

```
SELECT 
 A1."ObjectShipToPartyName",
 A1."ObjectShipToParty",
 A1."ObjShippedDate",
 A1."ObjInstalledDate",
 A1."ProductModelNumber",
 A1."RefProd",
 A1."RefProdDescription",
 A1."AssetType",
 A1."IbaseComponentType",
 A1."WarrantyStartDate",
 A1."WarrantyEndDate",
 A1."WarrantyStartDateStatus",
 A1."WarrantyEndDateStatus",
 A1."ValidWarrStartDate",
 A1."ValidWarrEndDate",
 A1."IbaseObjectID",
 A1."AssociatedIBaseID",
 A2."ContractID",
 Max(A2."HDRStartDate") AS "HDRStartDate",
 Max(A2."HDREndDate") AS "HDREndDate",
 A2."ContractType"

FROM "Table1" A1 

LEFT OUTER JOIN "Table2" A2
    ON LTRIM(A2."IBASEID", 0) = LTRIM(A1."AssociatedIBaseID", 0) 

WHERE A1."AssetType" = '01'
    AND Cast(A1."ObjShippedDate" AS Date) > TO_DATE('20070801', 'YYYYMMDD') 
    AND A2."LineStatusText" IN ('Active','Completed')
    AND A2."HDRStatusTxt" IN  ('Active','Completed')
    AND A2."ContractType" <> 'ZQAS'

 GROUP BY
 A1."ObjectShipToPartyName",
 A1."ObjectShipToParty",
 A1."ObjShippedDate",
 A1."ObjInstalledDate",
 A1."ProductModelNumber",
 A1."RefProd",
 A1."RefProdDescription",
 A1."AssetType",
 A1."IbaseComponentType",
 A1."WarrantyStartDate",
 A1."WarrantyEndDate",
 A1."WarrantyStartDateStatus",
 A1."WarrantyEndDateStatus",
 A1."ValidWarrStartDate",
 A1."ValidWarrEndDate",
 A1."IbaseObjectID",
 A1."AssociatedIBaseID",
 A2."ContractID",
 A2."ContractType"
```

Which gives Data that looks like this:
[image]

Here I only am interested in keeping the contract that is the highlighted row. Any help is greatly appreciated, I am fairly new to SQL.

Comment: How do you determine the most recent record here? Is it StartDate or EndDate? Can two records belonging to the same BaseID have the same Start/EndDates? If so, what's the tie-braker?

Comment: The most recent is determined by the end date, if there is a tie I would like it to fetch all records that tie (this is unlikely to happen though, it is a very small corner case here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common requirement. Based on your clarification a solution could look like this:

```
SELECT 
 A1."ObjectShipToPartyName",
 A1."ObjectShipToParty",
 A1."ObjShippedDate",
 A1."ObjInstalledDate",
 A1."ProductModelNumber",
 A1."RefProd",
 A1."RefProdDescription",
 A1."AssetType",
 A1."IbaseComponentType",
 A1."WarrantyStartDate",
 A1."WarrantyEndDate",
 A1."WarrantyStartDateStatus",
 A1."WarrantyEndDateStatus",
 A1."ValidWarrStartDate",
 A1."ValidWarrEndDate",
 A1."IbaseObjectID",
 A1."AssociatedIBaseID",
 A2."ContractID",
 A2."HDRStartDate"
 A2."HDREndDate"
 A2."ContractType"

FROM 
    "Table1" A1 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN "Table2" A2
    ON LTRIM(A2."IBASEID", 0) = LTRIM(A1."AssociatedIBaseID", 0) 

    inner join
         (SELECT "IBASEID", MAX("HDREndDate") as "MAX_HDREndDate"
          FROM "Table2" 
          WHERE 
                "LineStatusText" IN ('Active','Completed')
            AND "HDRStatusTxt" IN  ('Active','Completed')
            AND "ContractType" !='ZQAS'
          GROUP BY "IBASEID") S2

    on (A2."IBASEID", A2."HDREndDate") = (S2."IBASEID", S2."MAX_HDREndDate")

WHERE 
    A1."AssetType" = '01'
    AND TO_DATE(A1."ObjShippedDate") > TO_DATE('20070801', 'YYYYMMDD');
```

The aggregation needs to be on a separate level than the actual data collection. Therefore you first find all the most current/max dates per `IBASEID` then retrieve the details you need for those records.
The resulting set is what you join to your `Table1`.

Side remark: I would stick to one kind of type conversion (either `TO_DATE` or `CAST`) for readability. Also joining on the transformed `IBASEID` is not enhancing performance. A better option would be to store the data in the right format.